# Check correct delta in eps-delta proof

Tags: inequality, epsilon-delta

I been stuck now with this seemingly simple exercise for some time.

I need to show that:

$|x^2-4| < \epsilon$ when $0 < |x-2| < \epsilon(5+\epsilon)^{-1}$

But I'm at a loss.

I know that I somehow have to recognize that $|x^2 - 4| = |x-2||x+2| < \epsilon$ and then use this with the other inequality (for the delta) to prove these inequalities hold.

I would strongly appreciate any help.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Hint: If $|x-2| < { \epsilon \over 5+ \epsilon}$ then $|x+2| \le |x-2| + 4 \le { \epsilon \over 5+ \epsilon} + 4 = 5 ({ \epsilon+4\over \epsilon +5}) <5$.

Comment: Thank you. Yet I'm not completely sure if I got it right from here: I wrote: $|x-2| < \epsilon(\epsilon+5)^{-1}$
and
$|x+2| < 5 $ Thus $|x^2-4| = |x-2||x+2| < 5 \epsilon(\epsilon+5)^{-1} = \frac{5}{5/\epsilon+1} < \epsilon$ And then the delta satisfies that $|x^2-4| < \epsilon$ right?

Comment: I would be more inclined to write $\epsilon { 5 \over 5+ \epsilon} < \epsilon$ as it seems more clear to me. The above is correct, as long as you have established $|x+2| < 5$.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context.